# How to store collection of data under array index in firestore

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Structure of the databse]
I am currently developing application that store some trip's data on array. As we know in android development we can use hash-map for storing data into fire-store but that not fit what i need , it store the data without array index. is there any idea to structure the data as it shows on the attached screenshot. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To store an indexed array of items in the field of a document, use an ArrayList.